# Error value is not enumerable using RLM

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm using Realm with objective-c. I have to save an object that has an array of NSString as a property. So, I've created another custom object to encapsulate the NSString (it seems like the only way) and defined the property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) RLMArray<Signer *><Signer> *signers;
```

This is the class Signer:

```
@interface Signer : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;

@end
```

I'm getting the next error when trying to save one of this objects:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value Invalid value (documentsToSign) for 'Signer' array property 'Document.signers': value is not enumerable.'

I don't know the meaning. How can I make my object enumerable?

Comment: `custom object to encapsulate the NSString (it seems like the only way)` you haven't read [the change log for **Realm Cocoa 3.0.0's enhancement section**](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-release-notes-2017-10-16) have you?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, not all of it, no, but could you say something more? What have you seen there?

Comment: `RLMArray can now be constrained with the protocols RLMBool, RLMInt, RLMFloat, RLMDouble, RLMString, RLMData, and RLMDate in addition to protocols defined with RLM_ARRAY_TYPE. By default RLMArrays of non-RLMObject types can contain null. Indicating that the property is required (by overriding +requiredProperties:) will instead make the values within the array required. Querying RLMArrays containing values other than RLMObject subclasses is not yet implemented.`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So now I can create a RLMArray of NSString? And how it is defined?